# SSIS package failing with system resource exceeded error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an excel file connection manager which is around 200 MB from there we are loading file into SQL tables after using lookup container that uses full cache mode and a connection type as oledb Connection manager, rows are being redirected to no match output, everything works fine until number of unique rows cached steps, I have around 15 million rows that gets cached, after this step, the execute phase should start but what happens is that it completely skips execute phase and started post execute phase and write zero rows in the destinations and get failed, the error we get is Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "System resource exceeded.".
Any help that can solve this is really appreciated

Comment: Can you try running this in smaller batches?

Comment: I have tried this setting buffer etc nothing works..it's just so irritating...
Additionally an exe runs which pull data into various sheet in excel and then this excel is used to pull data into sql server tables....how can I monitor resources..it's just getting irritating